# Get another post values if post_share is not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a post table. This table has a field post_share. It is null by default. 
It has a value only if an user shared a post (with the post id).

```
`posts` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `text` text,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20),
  `post_share` int(11) UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I have a select to get posts:

```
select c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.text, pp.foto from posts p 
join users c on p.user=c.id 
left join profile_picture pp on p.user = pp.user
group by p.id
order by p.id desc limit 50
```

I get this values:

```
c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.text, pp.foto
```

what I'd like to do is get something like:

```
c.nome, p.foto, c.user, p.user, p.id, p.data, p.text, pp.foto, shared_post_text (the text from the post user is sharing - post_share id value), shared_post_user, shared_post_profile_picture, shared_post_date.
```

To sum up, this shared_ will have null if field post_share in table posts is null, but they will have another post value if it has an id. If post_share has an id I'd like to get values from this post on my select. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can `left join` the table to itself:

```
select  *
from    posts p 
left join
        posts linked
on      linked.id = p.post_share
```

If `post_share` is `null`, it will not find a result in the `posts` table.  A missed `left join` returns a single row with all `null` columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
   select c.nome, 
          p.foto, 
          c.user, 
          p.user, 
          p.id, 
          p.data, 
          p.text, 
          pp.foto,
          sp.text share_post_text,
          su.user shared_post_user, 
          spp.foto shared_post_profile_picture, 
          ss.date shared_post_date
     from posts p 
     join users c 
       on p.user=c.id 
left join profile_picture pp 
       on p.user = pp.user
left join posts sp
       on p.post_share= sp.id
left join users su
       on sp.user = su.id
left join profile_picture spp 
       on sp.user = spp.user
 group by c.nome, 
          p.foto, 
          c.user, 
          p.user, 
          p.id, 
          p.data, 
          p.text, 
          pp.foto,
          sp.text,
          su.user, 
          spp.foto, 
          ss.date 
    order by p.id 
     desc limit 50
```